# How to create Insecure Java grpc cilent for secure go grpc service

Tags: java, ssl, go, grpc, grpc-java

I am trying to create grpc service client in Java where server is in goLang and deployed with the https . where I am trying to achieve a non-secured connection [I don't want to pass the certificate ]

```
public class testgrpc {
    ManagedChannel channel ;
    ServiceGrpc.ServiceBlockingStub  blockingStub;
    String host = "remotesecuredhost";
    int port ="XXX";

    @Test
    public void testgrpc()
    {
    channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(host,port).build();

     blockingStub = ServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);

    response =  blockingStub.health(Empty.newBuilder().build());

    }

}
```

the above code gives following exception

```
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:221)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:202)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:131)
```

can someone help with Client code

Comment: What do you mean you don't want to pass the certificate? Is the go server using a custom CA for its certificate?

Comment: Not custom , but environment specific self signed certificates

Comment: or in other words I want to bypass the security certificates step , is this possible?

Comment: gRPC strongly discourages ignoring the certificates and doesn't "support" ignoring the certs, as that makes it effectively insecure; plaintext is much easier to use for that. We've found there's not been a use-case where it is necessary, even for testing with TLS. It is possible in Java by providing your own TrustManager, like Netty's InsecureTrustManagerFactory, but "you're on your own" when using it.

In your case, you could use a hard-coded cert on the server and still get the same effect, which would keep certificate verification enabled.

Comment: I have seen this code in go lib ---
conn, err := grpc.Dial(serverAddress, grpc.WithInsecure()) , would it also require certificates to be validated? would you be able to help with the trustmanager code exmple?

Comment: To mimic grpc.WithInsecure() you would do managedChannelBuilder.usePlaintext() in Java. There is no TLS in that case and so no certificate validation.

Comment: @EricAnderson thanks for your suggestions , I have finally found solution around it , it was mostly to do with infra side instead of client.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have figured out the solution finally , in my case

1. Netty versions were not in sync in my build.gradle , because of that I was receiving the exception as below

```
Could not find TLS ALPN provider; no working netty-tcnative,
Conscrypt, or Jetty NPN/ALPN available
```

to resolve this I have setup the versions as followed

> grpc-netty - 1.20.x-   |||    netty-handler-4.1.34.Final
>   |||   netty-tcnative-boringssl-static version  2.0.22.Final
>   [got idea from here](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/SECURITY.md#netty)

2. for tls connection this works

```
channel  = NettyChannelBuilder
                .forAddress("host",port)
               .sslContext(GrpcSslContexts.forClient().trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE).build())
                .build();
```

3. for non tls

```
              channel  = NettyChannelBuilder
            .forAddress("host",port).usePlaintext()
       .build();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import io.grpc.ManagedChannel;
import io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder;
import io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException;
import io.kubesure.publish.PublisherGrpc;
import io.kubesure.publish.PublisherProtos.Ack;
import io.kubesure.publish.PublisherProtos.Message;
import io.kubesure.publish.PublisherProtos.Message.Builder;

public class AppClient {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AppClient.class.getName());
    private final ManagedChannel channel;
    private final PublisherGrpc.PublisherBlockingStub blockingStub;

    public AppClient(String host, int port) {
        this(ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(host, port)
                // Channels are secure by default (via SSL/TLS). For the example we disable TLS
                // to avoid
                // needing certificates.
                .usePlaintext().build());
    }

    AppClient(ManagedChannel channel) {
        this.channel = channel;
        blockingStub = PublisherGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
    }

    public Ack publish(String payload) {
        logger.info("Payload sent to publisher ");
        Builder builder = Message.newBuilder();
        builder.setPayload(payload);
        builder.setVersion("v1");
        builder.setType("Policy");
        builder.setDestination("policyissued");
        Message message = builder.build();
        try {
            Ack ack = blockingStub.publish(message);
            logger.info("is published: " + ack.getOk());
            return ack;
        } catch (StatusRuntimeException e) {
            logger.log(Level.WARNING, "RPC failed: {0}", e.getStatus());
            return Ack.newBuilder().setOk(false).build(); 
        }
    }

    public void shutdown() throws InterruptedException {
        channel.shutdown().awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AppClient client = new AppClient("localhost", 50051);
        try {
            /* Access a service running on the local machine on port 50051 */
            String payload = "supplies to mars";
            if (args.length > 0) {
                payload = args[0]; /* Use the arg as the name to greet if provided */
            }
            client.publish(payload);
        } finally {
            client.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in my case If I run the similar code with my service it is throwing
INTERNAL: http2 exception
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INTERNAL: http2 exception
 at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:221)
 at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:202)
 at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:131)